# Xcode 8 libssl issue

Tags: xcode

After I've updated to Xcode 8, I'm no longer able to dynamically link `libssl` anymore. It is not available in the list of frameworks/libraries, which means that there is no `.tbd` file for the lib in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib/`. So ... it is removed from the SDK. Any ideas how to include `libssl` in the project as dynamic lib?

I.